# Closing file in Atom won't commit Git change to repository using "git commit -a"?

Tags: git, atom-editor

I'm closing the file and hoping it will commit the change to the Git repository but in the command prompt it simply says: `hint: "waiting for your editor to close the file"`.

The file remains in `Atom` under the `Git subfolder` of my project but if I delete it nothing happens.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It sounds like you set atom as your git editor without using the `--wait` flag: [check this blog post](https://blog.atom.io/2014/03/13/git-integration.html#commit-editor).

Comment: Still doesn't work after executing that code into the command line and rebooting atom. Not sure what other options I have.